# Trying to populate a textbox with the result from sql/vba and getting #Name error

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, textbox

I am trying to populate a textbox on an Access form with a value from a query where the selection criteria is another variable.
The code is generating the sql, which I then put into the rowsource of the textbox object but I just get a #Name in the textbox. 
The generated sql is working if I put it into the query builder and run it.

```
With Me.txtSupplier_ID
        .SetFocus
        .ControlSource = "(SELECT [Customer_ID] FROM [qrySelectCustData] WHERE [CustomerName] ='" & cVal & "')"
        .Requery

End With
```

The generated sql is working if I put it into the query builder and run it.

```
With Me.txtSupplier_ID
        .SetFocus
        .ControlSource = "(SELECT [Customer_ID] FROM [qrySelectCustData] WHERE [CustomerName] ='" & cVal & "')"
        .Requery

End With
```

The textbox should be populated with the customer id related to the customer name. The name is coming through fine and the controlsource is populated fine but still getting the #Name? error instead.

Comment: Textbox controls don't support SQL, nor can  they have sql as their data source. So, you have to use code + a record set, or use dlookup().

Answer (score 0):

You can't use SQL directly this way. Use *DLookup*:

```
.ControlSource = "=DLookup(""[Customer_ID]"",""[qrySelectCustData]"",""[CustomerName]='" & [cVal] & "'"")"
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I have used the code as specified but it's now returning the actual field value into the controlsource field in the properties window. This again is resulting in the #Name? error. I am assuming I can't just fill the textbox control on the fly with the value directly?

Comment: Right, it returned the value, not the expression. See edited answer, please.

Comment: Thanks guys. I got it working although it still needed a bit of tweaking but you certainly pointed me in the right direction. The final code was like this:      .ControlSource = "=DLookup(""[Customer_ID]"",""qrySelectCustData"", ""[CustomerName] =  '" & cVal & "'"")"